# PHP script returning false not sure why

Tags: php

My script is not working, and I have no idea why. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
    class email
    {
        function emailPlusAttachment($fromAddress,$toAddress,$mailSubject,$mailMessageHead,$mailMessageMain,$mailMessageSign,$filePath,$fileName)
        {

            $fileatt_name = $fileName;
            $fileatt = $filePath.$fileName;
            $fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream";
            $email_from = $fromAddress;
            $email_subject = $mailSubject;

            $email_message = $mailMessageHead. "<br>";
            $email_message .= $mailMessageMain. "<br>";
            $email_message .= $mailMessageSign;

            $email_to = $toAddress;

            $headers = "From: ".$email_from;

            $file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
            $data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
            fclose($file);

            $semi_rand = md5(time());
            $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

            $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
            "Content-Type: multipart/mixed:\n" .
            " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

            $email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
            "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
            $email_message .= "\n\n";

            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

            $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type}; \n" .
            " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
            $data .= "\n\n" .
            "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

            if (@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) 
            {
              return true;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

with:

```
    $from       =   'sender@tjaa.co.uk';
    $sendto     =   'recipient@hotmail.co.uk';
    $subject    =   'email with one attachment';
    $bodyHead   =   'Hello Drew';
    $bodyMain   =   'There is an attachment associated with this email.';
    $bodyEnd    =   'Thank you';
    $filePath   =   '';
    $fileName   =   'logo.png';

    if ($sendEmail->emailPlusAttachment($from,$sendto,$subject,$bodyHead,$bodyMain,$bodyEnd,$filePath,$fileName))
    {

        echo "email sent";
    }   
    else {echo "email not sent";}

?>
```

It simply `echo`s "email not send", indicating return false... any pointers?

What are the chances its a syntax error, or can anyone identify a bigger problem?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred are you indicating that if I added error reporting I would know the problem?

Comment: set it to catch and display to see if anything comes of it, yes. the `@` character btw, is an error suppressor. remove it during testing

Comment: so Fred I added error_reporting(E_ALL); but no errors are reported does that indicate its just terrible code then?

Answer (score 1):

`"Content-Type: multipart/mixed:\n" .`

Try changing the second `:` to `;`.

I used [Mailcatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/) to test your script, this was what it looked like [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wt3S.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRQn6.png) the header fix. Note that the mail tab is on HTML, not source.

[Mailcatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/) is great for testing email, but if you don't feel like setting things up, [Mailinator](https://www.mailinator.com/) is also really good (if your ISP doesn't block all mail sending ports).

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to consider (in addition to apricot boy's comments about the headers) is if your sendmail/mail() program is correctly configured for PHP to send -- i.e. running with the right rights.  Generically speaking, mail() can fail or close silently after writing to the sendmail pipe, without having access to an error, and sendmail may throw the email away if not properly configured.

If using sendmail, does PHP.ini also have the sendmail program set, and in the sendmail config, is the apache user a member of the trusted-users file?

Run a single simple "hello world" mail() test to yourself, does it go through?  I think there are 2 things to test & fix.  If apricot boy's changes don't fix it, more information will be required to diagnose.